# rails app, change root/specify root path

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, root

For some time I had a problem with my application following Wesley's Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial. Basically, the stylesheet wouldn't load up after which I realized that to default root seems to be the "app" folder since it looks in the /app/assets for the stylesheets. This is what the tutorial failed to explain and it had me make the stylesheet in /public/stylesheets.

Is there anyway I can change it so that the default folder would be /public/stylesheets or that if I specify the path "/public/stysheets/custom.css" it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css controls which css will be included in your app.

In application.css, you should see:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

You can add additional paths, like so (they're relative):

```
*= require_tree ../../../public/stylesheets/.
```

Any css files in said folder should be included in your app.

Comment: Please don't recommend to add `public/stylesheets`, as this is a bad coding practice. Please have all assets inside `app/assets`.

Comment: `public/stylesheets` should only be used for *static* stylesheets. By including them into the asset pipeline, you make it compile those assets too when they don't need to be compiled. Ergo, bad coding practice.